# Cisco Time-Domain Reflectometer (TDR) returns cable length of 65535 meters?

Tags: cisco, cable, errors, bug

Something very strange here. Today I noticed a device was unreachable. Giving a look at the switch it connects to (Cisco 3750, version 12.2(35)SE5), the port was in `err-disabled` due to `link-flap`:

```
#sh int g1/0/15 status err-disabled

Port      Name               Status       Reason
Gi1/0/15                     err-disabled link-flap
```

Trying a `shut` `no shut` on the interface, puts it again after a while on `err-disabled` due to `link-flap`.
Thinking of a possible physical problem I've run the (usually overlooked) `tdr` which surprisingly reported the cable as Normal despite estimated as **65535 meters long** and no pair on the other end.

```
#sh cable-diagnostics tdr int g1/0/15
TDR test last run on: March 01 01:11:00

Interface Speed Local pair Pair length        Remote pair Pair status
--------- ----- ---------- ------------------ ----------- --------------------
Gi1/0/15  100M  Pair A     65535 +/- 4  meters N/A         Normal
                Pair B     65535 +/- 4  meters N/A         Normal
                Pair C     65535 +/- 4  meters N/A         Normal
                Pair D     65535 +/- 4  meters N/A         Normal
```

`tdr` usually returns me useful values, but there's clearly something very wrong here. The number suggests me a kind or unhandled condition due to software bug.

In case of bad cable, `tdr` should just return `Open` or `Short` for affected pair(s). All other ports show correct results for `tdr`, in all cases (cable unplugged, cable plugged on switch only, cable ok, faulty cable).

Why is this test failing? Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: Which IOS version are you using?

Comment: 65535 is "-1". The test is failing, or the cable is unplugged.

Comment: @RickyBeam the cable is plugged as the port goes err-disabled. And the reason why the test is failing is the purpose of my question.

Comment: What does the log say is the reason for the err-disabled?

Comment: @RonTrunk link-flap. In fact, when I restart the port it quickly goes up and down several times until it's put in err-disabled

Comment: So have you done the basics? Clean the connectors? Swap transceiver?

Comment: @RonTrunk That's a TP port. ;-)

Comment: Whoops ;). Gotta pay more attention!

Comment: Bad cable, bad crimp, bad connector (bent pins, dirty, just plain designed wrong), bad solder joints, blown components... (I could fill a book with all the bad things I've seen over the decades.)

Comment: @RonMaupin edited question adding IOS version

Comment: @RickyBeam I'm not asking what's wrong with the cable. In case of bad cable, the tdr is supposed to return "open" or "short". I'm asking why the test fails